# finding gradient of an eingenline

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Trying to find the gradient of the eigenline that is ofcourse finding the eigenvlaue, but stuck here

QUESTION:

[image]

[image]

The matrix A has two eigenvalues h and k, where h > k.  To 2 decimal places, what is the gradient of the eigenline that corresponds to eigenvalue h?

My Working:
[image]

Comment: You need to solve the linear system which you have for $x$ and $y$. This will give you the equation of a line in $2D$ (barring calculation errors).

Comment: Not really sure how to get there, should I convert to y=mx+c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the matrix equation, this system is row-equivalent to the system
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}-3.526&-18&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right],$$
which is a consistent linear system. Performing back substitution gives
$$-3.526x+18y=0,$$
which is the standard form for the equation of a line (equivalent to $y=\frac{3.526}{18}x$).

Comment: so the gradient m = $3.526 / 18$ ?

Comment: I reckon that is correct. Do you understand the process?

Comment: except the part why the bottom ones are 0's? I understand the top part

Comment: I performed the row operation $R_2\leftarrow R_2-\frac{5}{3.526}R_1$ as a part of the procedure of row reducing the matrix system.